# Is Stack Overflow meant for posting a Q&A about a library that I created?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I built a geocoding library in Java, and I keep on getting asked a bunch of times how to use a certain aspect of it.

Is Stack Overflow a good place for me to post the question and answer myself to that question so that when people google it they will find the answer?

Comment: You might come at risk to be accused spamming.

Comment: For companies there's a restriction, they shouldn't outsource their support to Stack Exchange. I'm not sure how far this could also apply for your case.

Comment: This seems fine to me, people ask questions about libraries all the time. That said, if people dont understand how to use a certain aspect of your library, maybe you need to see if you can make that aspect more intuitive as well as improving your documentation on that aspect.